# .htaccess URL Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule managerestaurantimages/(.*) index.php?page=managerestaurantimages&id=$1 [L]
```

this rewrite work for

- /managerestaurantimages/

but not working for

- /managerestaurantimages/user_id

how i can rewrite to work for both types?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The pattern you use certainly _does_ match for that case. So it is unclear what you actually ask...

Comment: for url  http:localhost/project/managerestaurantimages  it works, but for url http:localhost/project/managerestaurantimages/1234   it is not working

Comment: Repeating things you already posted do not help, sorry. My question was: What do you mean by "not working"? You did not answer that question at all...

Comment: without 2nd parameter redirecting to the desired page and with 2nd parameter not redireting.

Comment: i want to redirect it with the id also as it is redirecting without id parameter

Comment: As said: the pattern looks fine, that `user_id` _should_ be handed over, as far as I can see. You may want to add a "line end anchor" to the pattern, but I doubt this is the issue here: `RewriteRule managerestaurantimages/(.*)$ index.php?page=managerestaurantimages&id=$1 [L]` Note the additional `$` after the `(.*)`. Could it be that you fail to correctly read the `id` parameter from the `$_GET` array in your `index.php` script?